# Looping through collection

Tags: java

I got a problem with this code:

```
for (String functionChain : stringCollection) {
 lblSource.setText(functionChain);
 System.out.print(functionChain);
}
```

I want to set the text to lblSource as a "chain" of all the collected strings.
It does work with the System.out , i mean it does output as I want but it doesnt Set the Text to the Label, it only sets the LAST valor of the array.
Why is this happening? I mean, the system.out is fine and i am taking same variable "functionChain"... However the output is different in the system.out as in the label.

Comment: You're looking for something in the nature of `lblSource.setText(lblSource.getText() + functionChain);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the old value first and concatenate.

```
lblSource.setText(lblSource.getText() + functionChain);
```

Answer (score 2):

`setText()` does what it sounds like it does: it sets the text of the label.

Try this instead:

```
String s = "";
for (String functionChain : stringCollection) {
    s += functionChain;
    System.out.print(functionChain);
}
lblSource.setText(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

`lblSource.setText(functionChain)` will over write the existing value with new value.

To have all the values of string collection , loop through the string collection , append the values and then set the value to `lblSource`.

eg :

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
```

loop through the collection.

```
sb.append(each value);
sb.append (",") // a separator if required
```

then

```
lblSource.setText(sb.toString())
```